# Relative Positioned Footer - White Space under in IE?

Tags: css

I have a Footer that spans the width of the page.  Within the footer there is an  which is essentially acting as a footer background image that fills the entire width of the footer / page.  However, in IE, there is some white space under the footer, when it should just be flush with the bottom of the page.  Seems fine in Firefox, Safari, etc.  Here's what I have, any recommendations on something to try?

```
<body>
     <div id='container'>
          <div id='content'></div
     </div>

     <div id='footer'></div>
</body>
```

CSS Is:

```
html {
    font:62.5% 'Helvetica Neue';
    color:#777676;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    font-size:1.8em; /* 18 px */
    line-height:1.2em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

#container {
    width:906px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}

#content {
    padding-top:20px;
}

div#footer {
    position:relative; 
    bottom:0; 
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

div#footer img {
    width:100%;
    border:0 none;
}
```

Comment: A live demo of this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block;` on the image, that should fix it...

(and use code highlighting in your question if you want `<tags>` to be visible in your text...)

Answer (score 0):

That could be a very involved answer. I have ran into this before and I forget now how I solved it. First, I should ask which version of IE your testing in, it could be old. I don't think this is as much of an issue in IE 8 and above. Next, is your DOCTYPE set. Then try setting the height and/or line-height on the footer. Make sure all sibling and parent elements have their "position", "top", and "left" set.

Have you tried positioning it "absolute" and if that doesn't work remove all other elements in the body, adding them back in one at a time till it breaks and then figure out what is wrong with the element you added.